aircraft-database.com Creator(s)
Recently, the incredibly extensive open-source aircraft and engine database aircraft-database.com was sunset by its creator(s?). All that remains of the website at the moment are snapshots at the Internet Archive, mentioning:

Website is no longer updated and will be sunset on December 31st, 2023.

Data from the database continues to be used in other aircraft databases, such as the aero-database.com.
Since the data was made available under the permissive Open Data Commons Attribution License (ODC-By) v1.0, it could simply be uploaded to a resarch data repository such as Zenodo.
I just am wondering if anything is known about the creator(s) of the aircraft-database.com. The WHOIS record of the domain never listed an individual owner... and a web search does not yield any results either. It would be great to credit the actual creators during re-publication of the data.

If you don't have any other possibility, you can ask the registrar (OVH). As the registrant, the hosting company and registrar are under French law, it should be possible to disclose the legal owner of the site (actually it should have been published in the Legal section).
